# While loop terminating incorrectly

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with my while loop terminating, even though a 5 or 6 isn't entered. Thanks!

```
int main() {

    char choice;
    int num = 0;
    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit)
    {
        std::cin>>num;
        std::cout << num << '\n';
        if(num == 5 || 6)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "|" is a bit wise operator not a logical operator. You should be using this "||".  if (num ==5 || num==6)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you meant to put this: `if(num == 5 || num == 6)` as your condition `|| 6` is a non zero value and so evaluates to true everytime.

Comment: I made a mistake copying the code, sorry about that - this was the right answer, my bad for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

All right. You're encountering a bit of misunderstanding on your part, aggravated by a wart in the C language.

The `==` operator only compares values, it won't look in a list. It returns 1 or 0, which represents true or false respectively.

The `|` operator is the "binary-or" operator. It performs an operation comparing the values of two numbers bit by bit ( this is known as a bit-wise operation ). The `|` sets the bit in the final number to 1 if the same bit is 1 in either of the given numbers.

```
0b00 | 0b00 -> 0b0000
0b10 | 0b00 -> 0b0010
0b00 | 0b10 -> 0b0010
0b10 | 0b11 -> 0b0011
```

The `||` operator is the "logical-or" operator, and returns 1, meaning true, if either of its given expressions yield 1. If the left expression yields 1, it doesn't bother to execute the right one ( this is known as short circuiting ).

HOWEVER, when they were initially creating C, they did something that has plagued the language since. They made `==` bind tighter than `|` in the order of operations ( also known as operator precedence ). This means `( 1 == 2 | 3 )` does not mean "the result of comparing 1 to the result of taking the binary or of 2 and 3", but instead means "the result of taking the binary or of ( the result of comparing 1 and 2 ) and 3".

It means `( ( 1 == 2 ) | 3 )`, where `( 1 == ( 2 | 3 ) )` is what most would expect before being made aware of this oddity.

All this taken together, your if statement means:

```
if ( num == 5 ) | 6:
  quit()
```

Which is very likely to quit for numbers other than 5 or 6! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement isn't doing what you think it does. Try this:

```
if(num == 5 || num == 6)
```

"Or" in C++ is || not a single bar.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted. The code is correct, although it has too many parentheses.